# How to import a range into a variant array in Excel VBA and sort using the sort method?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm trying to assign a range to an array (by values) in VBA, and use the sort method on it. I can't sort it in the sheet since it is based on formulas and Excel keeps trying to sort based on the formulas.

So something like this would be succinct, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim TU As Variant
TU = Range("Thermal_Units").Sort key1:=Range("Thermal_Units").Columns(28), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish the assignment and the sort? Or am I forced to just write a sort routine to apply after the assignment?

Comment: Something like `TU = Evaluate("SORT(Thermal_Units,28)")` maybe

Comment: A walk around solution: copy `Range("Thermal_Units")` to a new sheet, load into an array after sorting the table, then remove the sheet

Comment: If you have MS365, you can try `TU = Application.Sort(Range("Thermal Units"), 28, 1)`. If this doesn't work as expected, you could try `TU = Range("Thermal Units").Value: TU = Application.Sort(TU, 28, 1)` or use another *Variant* for the 2nd equation. BTW, descending is `-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Did this late in the workday here, so I'll be testing these ideas on Monday.

Comment: Looking forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel will sort ranges with formulas correctly if you absolutize them (or they can be relative if in the same row).

If you don't want to sort the range directly on the worksheet, you can use Evaluate method mentioned by Tim, or you can use the following code:

```
Sub adasd()
  Dim a As Variant
  a = WorksheetFunction.Sort(Range("A1:B4"))
End Sub
```

It works with the snapshot of the range (values).

Then you can put the result back to the worksheet onto the same or another location:

```
Sub adasd()
  Dim a As Variant
  a = WorksheetFunction.Sort(Range("A1:B4"))
  Range("C3:D6") = a
End Sub
```

**Side note.**

There are three same ways to access the worksheet functions:

"Application.Sort" = "Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort" = "WorksheetFunction.Sort", where Sort is one of the available functions (as example).